# Как в реактивной форме связать get/set с контролом?

Tags: typescript, angular

Есть модель:

```
export class People {
  address: string;
  document: {
    number: string;
    serial: string;
    lastName: string;
  };
  ...
  ctor
  ...
  get serialNumber() {
    return this.document.serial || '' + ' ' + this.document.number;
  }
  set serialNumber(value) {
    console.log('значения', value);
    const [serial, number] = value.split('');
    this.document.serial = serial;
    this.document.number = number;
  }
}
```

Есть компонент формы (PeopleForm):

```
this.people = new People();
this.peopleForm = new FormGroup({
      address: new FormControl(this.people.address, []),
      document: new FormGroup({
        lastName: new FormControl(this.people.document.lastName, []),
        serialNumber: new FormControl(this.people.serialNumber, []),
        license: new FormControl(this.people.document.license, [])
      })
});
```

У меня, как видно из модели, есть в документах два свойства:
**serial**, **number**.
Я хотел бы, чтобы в форме эти два свойства были в под единым именем **serialNumber** (чтобы маску накинуть какую-нибудь).
В модели создал get/set, но, увы, почему-то не сработало.

Подскажите, как решить проблему-задачу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите связать форму с вашей моделью `People`. Ну смотрите, первый вариант это просто слушать изменение значения формы и сеттить это значение в объект `people`:

```
private readonly destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

constructor() {
  this.peopleForm.valueChanges.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroy$)
  ).subcribe((value) => {
    this.setValue(value);
  });
}

public ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.destroy$.next();
  this.destroy$.complete();
}

private setValue(value: People): void {
  for (const key of Object.keys(value)) {
    if (this.people.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      this.people[key] = value[key];
    }
  }
}
```

Здесь мы не сеттим значение объекта `value` напрямую в `people` (`this.people = value`), потому что генерируемое значение потока `valueChanges` - это объектный литерал, а мы не хотим потерять функциональность класса `People`.

Проблемой данного подхода является несовпадение ключей модели объекта, который генерирует форма, и вашей модели `People`.

Лучше вариант - это явная работа с формой и подписка на каждый контрол по отдельности (так вы будете на 100% уверены, что засеттилось нужное свойство), в классе `People` вы можете создать несколько методов для работы с каждым контролом по отдельности, параметром будут принимать сами контролы и генератор:

```
export class People {
  private listenToControl(control: AbstractControl, destroy$: Subject<void>) {
    return control.valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(destroy$));
  }

  public listenToAddressControl(
    control: AbstractControl,
    destroy$: Subject<void>
  ): void {
    this.listenToControl(control, destroy$).subscribe((address) => {
      this.address = address;
    });
  }

  public listenToSerialNumberControl(
    control: AbstractControl,
    destroy$: Subject<void>
  ): void {
    this.listenToControl(control, destroy$).subscribe((serialNumber) => {
      this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
    });
  }
}
```

И вызывать эти методы следующим образом:

```
this.people.listenToAddressControl(this.peopleForm.get('address'), this.destroy$);
this.people.listenToSerialNumberControl(
  this.peopleForm.get('document').get('serialNumber'),
  this.destroy$
);
```

Есть дублирование кода? Конечно. Похоже на анти-паттерн? Не совсем, потому что вы явно управляете потоками данных, также исключаете всевозможные утечки памяти.

Было бы, естественно, в 100 раз легче решить такую задачу, если б ваш объект `people` был простым объектным литералом, но вы работаете с инстансом класса `People`, у которого есть своя бизнес логика, сеттеры, геттеры и т.д.

Можно конечно попытаться схитрить, чтоб избежать дублирования:

```
export const enum PeopleProperty {
  Address,
  Number,
  Serial,
  LastName
}

export class People {
  public listenToControl(
    control: AbstractControl,
    destroy$: Subject<void>,
    property: PeopleProperty
  ): void {
    control.valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(destroy$)).subscribe((value) => {
      this.setValue(property, value);
    });
  }

  private setValue(property: PeopleProperty, value: any): void {
    switch (property) {
      case PeopleProperty.Address: {
        return this.address = value;
      }

      case PeopleProperty.Number: {
        return this.document.number = value;
      }

      case PeopleProperty.Serial: {
        return this.serialNumber = value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Тогда код сеттинга контролов превращается в:

```
this.people.listenToControl(
  this.peopleForm.get('document').get('serialNumber'),
  this.destroy$,
  PeopleProperty.Serial
);
```

Comment: Спасибо,  в целом понял (3ий метод приятнее будет), единственное, думал, что не так нагружено всё будет